# Increase performance in an R function using a vectorized approach

Tags: performance, r, iteration, vectorization

## Goal

Write an `R` function to generate probabilities modeled by the following equation (IRT; 2 Parameter Logistic Model):
[image]

## Data

```
set.seed(1)
a = runif(10, 1.5, 3)
b = rnorm(10, 0, 1)
theta = rnorm(10000000)
# the output of the implementation should result in 
# a matrix with 100 mil. rows and 10 columns
```

## Implementation

**Strategy A**

```
# the implementation of the equation
computeProbability = function(theta, b, a) {
    x = exp(1) ^ (a * (theta - b))
    return(x / (1 + x))
}

strategy.A = function(theta, b, a) {
    n.rows = length(theta)
    n.cols = length(b)

    prob_mtx = matrix(nrow = n.rows, ncol = n.cols)

    for(i in 1:n.rows)
    {
        prob_mtx[i, ] = computeProbability(theta[i], b, a)
    }
    return(prob_mtx)
}
```

**Strategy B**

```
strategy.B = function(theta, b, a) {
   return(t(sapply(theta, computeProbability, b = b, a = a)))
}
```

**Strategy C**

```
strategy.C = function(theta, b, a) {
    return(1 / (1 + exp(-sweep(outer(theta, b, "-"), 2, a, "*"))))
}
```

## Timings

```
    # Strategy A        |       # Strategy B        |       # Strategy C
                        |                           |
 user  system elapsed   |    user  system elapsed   |   user  system elapsed
64.76    0.27   65.08   |   82.01    0.91   82.93   |   7.81    0.64    8.46
```

---

**Question:** *Strategy C* is by far the most efficient way, but how can I make it even faster?

Comment: That specific question isn't on-topic on this site, but we can review the code as it is instead.

Comment: Oh, my apologies. I thought it was too vague for StackOverflow.

Comment: [Here](http://www.noamross.net/blog/2014/4/16/vectorization-in-r--why.html) is a great article that explains what is meant by vectorization in R.

Comment: @Samuel It is really helpful. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Your strategy C is probably already nearly optimal. Here is an [Rcpp](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html) based solution to squeeze out some additional seconds

```
library('Rcpp')
cppFunction(includes = '#include <math.h>',
            code = 'Rcpp::NumericMatrix strategy_rcpp(const Rcpp::NumericVector& theta,
                                                      const Rcpp::NumericVector& b,
                                                      const Rcpp::NumericVector& a) {
  const int n = theta.size();
  const int m = a.size();
  if (m != b.size())
      Rcpp::stop("a and b must have equal length");
  const double e = exp(1.0);
  Rcpp::NumericMatrix ret(n, m);
  for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
      for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
         ret(i, j) = 1.0 / (1.0 + pow(e, -a[j] * (theta[i] - b[j])));
      }
  }
  return ret;
}')
```

Benchmarks with your data:

```
library('microbenchmark')
microbenchmark(times = 1,
               strategy.C(theta, b, a),
               strategy_rcpp(theta, b, a)
)

Unit: seconds                                                                
                       expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq
    strategy.C(theta, b, a) 10.996822 10.996822 10.996822 10.996822 10.996822
 strategy_rcpp(theta, b, a)  6.921705  6.921705  6.921705  6.921705  6.921705
```